# Why is benzenediazonium fluoroborate stable at room temperature and insoluble in water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image]

I think that as it is diazosalt it shouldn't be stable at room temperature. But it is stable. How is that possible?
And it is ionic hence insoluble in water. 
Why?